# Scope with conditions based on associated models

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, scope

I'm trying to write a multi-conditional scope in my Rails 4 app.

```
class Receipt
  # Scope to only get Receipt objects that need to be sent out.
  def self.needs_send_receipts
    where(sent_receipt: false) && company.employees.size > 0 && company.teams.first.action_items.size >= 15
  end
end
```

This doesn't work, and I'm trying to figure out why, should it evaluate to true and return information.

Comment: this `company.teams.first.action_items.size` is a crazy associations chain :)

Comment: let me know if my answer was of any help (if you tried it)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with (**warning:** heavy usage of [`scope`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope)s):

1. Add a scope to `Team` model, that selects objects, that have at least 15 `action_items` and limits amount to 1:

   ```
   class Team
     # company.teams.first.action_items.size >= 15
     scope :some_action_items, lambda {
       joins(:action_items)
        .group('teams.id')
        .having('COUNT(action_items.id >= 15').limit(1)
     }
   end
   ```
2. Add a scope to `Company` model, that selects objects, which have at least one associated `employee`:

   ```
   class Company
     # company.employees.size > 0
     scope :with_employees, -> { joins(:employees) }
   end
   ```
3. Finally, use these scope in you `Receipt` model, to query for `receipts` taking into account all above conditions by means of [`merge`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge)'ing scopes:

   ```
   class Receipt
     # where(sent_receipt: false)
     scope :receipt_not_sent, -> { where(sent_receipt: false) }

     # Scope to only get Receipt objects that need to be sent out
     scope :needs_send_receipts, lambda {
       receipt_not_sent
         .joins(company: [:employees, teams: :action_items])
         .merge(Company.with_employees)
         .merge(Team.some_action_items)
     }
   end
   ```

I hope you realize that I had not even a smallest chance to test it, so in case of any typos/mistakes/etc don't run into commenting

> I have an error saying `you have mistyped a single letter` your solution
>   does not work atata

but instead just try to follow the idea and you'll figure it out :)